# Check all elements in form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I know javascript in the beginning level, but I have a problem.

I have **7** input elements in a form and I want all of them to be filled. 
I came up with this idea but it looks **disgusting**.

Can someone help me how to check **whether all form elements are filled or not?**

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["register"]["name"].value;
var y=document.forms["register"]["phone"].value;
var z=document.forms["register"]["compname"].value;
var q=document.forms["register"]["mail"].value;
var w=document.forms["register"]["compphone"].value;
var e=document.forms["register"]["adres"].value;
var r=document.forms["register"]["zip"].value;
if (x==null || x=="" || y==null || y=="" || z==null 
|| z=="" || q==null || q=="" ||  w==null || w=="" || e==null || e=="" 
|| r==null || r=="")
{
alert("Please fill all the inputs");
return false;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Would a jQuery solution work for you?

Comment: use a loop to do the same thing many times...

Comment: you could use a loop of Tag input

Comment: *Slightly* less **disgusting** - take advantage of the falsiness of "", and make your `if` statement: `if (!x || !y || !z || !q || !w || !e || !e)`

Comment: Take a look at this :http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/MuDUp/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the simple and dirty way.

A better way is to update a validation message that the fields are required.

```
function validateForm()
{
  var fields = ["name, phone", "compname", "mail", "compphone", "adres", "zip"]

  var i, l = fields.length;
  var fieldname;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    fieldname = fields[i];
    if (document.forms["register"][fieldname].value === "") {
      alert(fieldname + " can not be empty");
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Jeremy, does placeholder breaks this if check? I'm so noob on js

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry.

Comment: <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="yourmail@address.com" name="email" /> Does this still count "empty"?

Comment: Yes, it still counts as empty.  The placeholder doesn't change the `value` of an input element, only how it displays.

Answer (score 6):

With some simple vanilla JS, you can handle this in a lot more simplified way:

JavaScript

```
function validateForm(){
    var form = document.getElementById("register"), inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input"), input = null, flag = true;
    for(var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        input = inputs[i];
        if(!input.value) {
            flag = false;
            input.focus();
            alert("Please fill all the inputs");
            break;
        }
    }
    return(flag);
}
```

Then make sure you `return` the function within your form, either inline (bad practice):

```
<form name="register" id="register" method="post" action="path/to/handler.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

Or in a more unobtrusive way:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var form = document.getElementById("register");
    form.onsubmit = function(){
        var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input"), input = null, flag = true;
        for(var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
            input = inputs[i];
            if(!input.value) {
                flag = false;
                input.focus();
                alert("Please fill all the inputs");
                break;
            }
        }
        return(flag);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>
  <title> Event Program</title>
  <script>
  function validateForm() {
    var fields = ["name, phone", "compname", "mail", "compphone", "adres", "zip"]
    var i, l = fields.length;
    var fieldname;
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      fieldname = fields[i];
      if(document.forms["register"][fieldname].value === "") {
        alert(fieldname + " can not be empty");
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  var _validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png"];
  var fields = {
    "eventName": "Event Name",
    "eventDate": "Event Date",
    "eventPlace": "Event Place"
  }

  function Validate(oForm) {
    var arrInputs = oForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
      var oInput = arrInputs[i];
      if(oInput.type == "text" && oInput.value == "") {
        alert(fields[oInput.name] + " cannot be empty");
        return false;
      }
      if(oInput.type == "file") {
        var sFileName = oInput.value;
        if(sFileName.length > 0) {
          var blnValid = false;
          for(var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
            var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
            alert(sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase())
            if(sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
              blnValid = true;
              break;
            }
          }

          if(!blnValid) {
            alert("Sorry, " + sFileName + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div align="center">
    <h3>Event Management</h3>
    <form onsubmit="return Validate(this);" id='eventForm' name='eventForm' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='saveEvent.php'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Event Name</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="eventName">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Event Date</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="eventDate" id='datepicker'>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Event place</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="eventPlace">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Upload Image</td>
          <td>
            <input type="file" name="my file" />
            <br />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>About Events</td>
          <td>
            <textarea></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan=2 align=center>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="button" name="clear" value="Clear" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
  });

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please explain your answer

Answer (score -2):

You could just do this:

```
//Declare variables
var 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7;
1 = document.getElementById("Field Id");
2 = document.getElementById("Field Id");
3 = document.getElementById("Field Id");
4 = document.getElementById("Field Id");     //Define variable values
5 = document.getElementById("Field Id");
6 = document.getElementById("Field Id");
7 = document.getElementById("Field Id");

//Check if any of the fields are empty
If (1 == "" || 2 == "" || 3 == "" || 4 == "" || 5 == "" || 6 == "" || 7 == "") {
  alert("One or more fields are empty!");
  //Other code
}
```

I used this for my own form and it works fine while not taking up to much space or looking too "ugly". It works for all field elements and checks the value entered.